# How can I return from a function to end a test without ending the script?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, autoit

I am writing automated tests using AutoIt:

```
Func MyTest($sInput)
   Local $oTest = NewTest("Test Name")
   $oTest.Setup()
   ;Run steps
   $oTest.Assert($sSomeExpected, $sSomeActual)
   $oTest.Teardown()
EndFunc
```

Inside `Assert()` I set test's result to failed if the assertion fails. I would like to end the test completely but not the entire script, because my script looks like this:

```
For $i = 0 To UBound($aInputs) - 1 Step 1
   MyTest($aInputs[$i])
Next
```

If the test fails for input 1 I still want to run the test for the other inputs. Ideally I want to handle this in `Assert()`:

```
Func _assert($oSelf, $sExpected, $sActual)
   If Not($sExpected = $sActual) Then
      $oSelf.Result = 0
      ;Return from MyTest function without ending script??
   EndIf
EndFunc
```

Is it possible to return from `MyTest()` from inside `Assert()`? I can exit the script but that requires one script for every test which gets bloated quick. The workaround I have is awful (return True/False from `Assert()` and check it in `MyTest()`):

```
If Not($oTest.Assert($sSomeExpected, $sSomeActual)) Then Return
```

It makes code unreadable and difficult to maintain. Is there a way to have `MyTest()` return if `Assert()` fails without handling it each time I call `Assert()`?